# Error in f2(x, ...) : could not find function "n": I am not using any function "n" nor defined it

Tags: r, optimization

I was solving an optimization problem in R using "nloptr" package.

```
 N_h <- c(39552, 38347, 43969, 36942, 41760)
 s_h1 <- c(4.6, 3.4, 3.3, 2.8, 3.7)
 s_h2 <- c(11.7, 9.8, 7.0, 6.5, 9.8)
 s_h3 <- c(332, 357, 246, 173, 279)

 N <- sum(N_h)
 d_h <- c(N_h/N)
 d1 <- c(s_h1[1]*(d_h[1])^2, s_h1[2]*(d_h[2])^2, s_h1[3]*(d_h[3])^2,s_h1[4]*(d_h[4])^2, s_h1[4]*(d_h[5])^2)
 d2 <- c(s_h2[1]*(d_h[1])^2, s_h2[2]*(d_h[2])^2, s_h2[3]*(d_h[3])^2,s_h2[4]*(d_h[4])^2, s_h2[4]*(d_h[5])^2)
 d3 <- c(s_h3[1]*(d_h[1])^2, s_h3[2]*(d_h[2])^2, s_h3[3]*(d_h[3])^2, s_h3[4]*(d_h[4])^2, s_h3[4]*(d_h[5])^2)
 library('nloptr')

 #Objective function
 f0 <- function(n, d1=d1, d2=d2, d3=d3){
  return(n[6])  
 }

#Constraints
g0 <- function(n, d1, d2, d3){
return(c(
(n[1]+n[2]+n[3]+n[4]-1065), 
(w1*(d1[1]/n[1]+d1[2]/n[2]+d1[3]/n[3]+d1[4]/n[4]+d1[5]/n[5]-n(6))+w2*(d2[1]/n[1]+d2[2]/n[2]+d2[3]/n[3]+d2[4]/n[4]+d2[5]/n[5]-n(6))
+w3*(d3[1]/n[1]+d3[2]/n[2]+d3[3]/n[3]+d3[4]/n[4]+d3[5]/n[5]-n(6))
)) )
}

 #Initialization
 n<- c(2,2,2,2,2,100)
 w1=0.333
 w2=0.333
 w3=0.333
 Rob1 <- cobyla(n, f0, hin = g0, nl.info = TRUE, control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-8, maxeval = 4000), d1=d1, d2=d2, d3=d3)
```

It shows following error

```
   Error in f2(x, ...) : could not find function "n"
```

I have not defined any function "n" nor I need it.

Could you please help me where I am doing a mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your code, you have `n(6)` rather than `n[6]`. This makes `n` look like a function rather than a vector. This is just a typo.

Comment: I was just writing the same. As `n`is a vector, the element should be called as `n[6]`. With `n(6)` understands that `n` is a function and `6` its parameter.

Comment: Ohh... Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help.